# javascript parameter passed to method by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a view in MVC where I select a combobox connected to sqlserver, taking the value selected and sent to a method that is in the controller, but selecting the value does not show me the data table corresponding to the selected value.

Code: My Method Query and and use of the method is the next:

```
    public List<Ciudades> GetCityById(int id)
     {
         List<Ciudades> lct2 = new List<Ciudades>();

         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
         {
             string sql = string.Format("Select cityID,cityName from loccities where countryID={0}",id);
             cmd.Connection = con;
             cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
             cmd.CommandText =  sql;
             con.Open();
             SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             while (sdr.Read())
             {
                 Ciudades ct = new Ciudades();
                 ct.ID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["cityID"]);
                 ct.Nombre = sdr["cityName"].ToString();
                 lct2.Add(ct);
             }
             return lct2;
         }
     }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetDataById(int id)
    {

        MvcSRDCBeta.Models.Ciudades obj = new MvcSRDCBeta.Models.Ciudades();
        var Respuesta = var1.GetCityById(id);
        return Json(Respuesta, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

At the view I have the following javascript code and where I have problems with the line $ .post ("GetDataById ($ _ POST ['code'])"

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id" class="col-md-2 control-label">Prueba C4</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <select class="form-control" name="optone" id="countrySel" size="1">
                <option value="">Select Countries</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <select class="form-control" name="opttwo" id="cities" size="1">
                <option value="">Selecciona cities</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <select class="form-control" name="optthree" id="regionSel" size="1">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Please select city first</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

i change the js in load page

```
function obtener_ciudades() {  //Funcion para obtener los estados de cada pais 
$("#countrySel").change(function () {
    $("#cities option").remove();
    $("#cities").append('<option value="">Selecciona Ciudades</option>');
    var datos = {
        //accion: "obtener_estados",
        codigo: $(this).val()
    }
    //console.log(datos);
    $.post("GetDataById($_POST['codigo'])", datos, function (datos) {
        console.log(datos);
        $.each(datos, function (key, value) {
            $("#cities").appendChild("<option value=" + value.ID + ">" + value.Nombre + "</option>");
        });
    }, "json");

});



 $(document).on("ready", inicio);

function inicio() { //inicializar funciones vitales para las paginas
    obtener_ciudades();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your address is incorrect. You don't need to use `$_POST['codigo']` (looks like some kind of PHP code) in your call. The address that you need is `/ControllerName/MethodName`. Just change

```
$.post("GetDataById($_POST['codigo'])", datos, function (datos) {
```

to (replace ControllerName with actual controller name):

```
$.post("/ControllerName/GetDataById", datos, function (datos) {
```

Next, since your method `GetDataById` expects single parameter named Id, you need to provide an object that has a property id, e.g.

```
$.post("/ControllerName/GetDataById", { id: $(this).val() }, function (datos) {
```

Comment: Thank's, proved successful, only change the appendChild for append,

Comment: @RafaelMendoza any reason you are not using EF. and you can simplify your $.post("/ControllerName/GetDat...... by removing the "}, "json");" and just making it "});"